# Not Understanding Servlet RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlets

I have one doubt in Servlet RequstDispatcher. it has 2 methods(include and forward) right. my doubt is what happen when we use forward method following by include method..

```
RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/S2"); 
rd.forward(req, res);
rd.include(req, res);
```

in this case these 2 methods executing fine or not ..

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

`public void forward(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)throws ServletException,java.io.IOException`

Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server.

`public void include(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)throws ServletException,java.io.IOException`

Includes the content or data of a resource (servlet, JSP page, or HTML file) in the response.

More information on : http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher-in-servlet

Comment: @ Vishvesh Phadnis

Thanks for your response sir...ur answer is good and i know these points. but my doubt is, "is  it posible to use both forward and include in same function. i mean forward() followed by inclued().."..hope u understand..kindly help me...

Thanks in advance,